# Spring boot JPA CrudRepository for a different oracle schema

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot application,
application is working fine, reading from the DB with no issue.

```
//working fine on schema PRINTERS_SCHEMA
public interface PrinterRepository extends CrudRepository<PrinterInfo,String>{}
```

my question is how to go about adding a new Repository reading from a different oracle schema?

```
//need this repository to read from EMPLOYEE_ SCHEMA   
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<EmployeeInfo,String>{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using 2 different entities, you can specify the schema on the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "employeeschema")
public class EmployeeInfo
```